# How to add whitespace between table columns

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to format a table such that there is whitespace between particular columns with css.

Before:

```
--------------
th1  th2  th3
--------------
col1 col2 col3
--------------
```

What I want:

```
--------- ----
th1  th2  th3
--------- ----
col1 col2 col3
--------- ----
```

Where the break can occur at an arbitrary position - not necessarily second to last. Also I'd like to have multiple column breaks.

Using React - I could probably set up a flexbox and split the data into multiple tables, but I was wondering if there's an easier way with css

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-of-type` selector on your css ([see some examples here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp))

For your case, we can do the following:

```css
tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
 margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

You can generalize this for any columns you want

```css
tr td:nth-of-type(2), tr th:nth-of-type(5) { /* second and fifth colums */
tr td:nth-of-type(3n) { /* every three columns in a row
```

Look on the Internet. There are plenty of examples of how to use this selector.
P.S.: You also should use `tr th:nth-of-type()` for the table heads